# A universal .NET server for clients written for different platforms

Tags: android, ios, .net, client-server

I want to create a sort of chat system with a server, and client applications designed for both desktop and mobile platforms. The server and the desktop client would both be written in .NET (for Windows only). The mobile clients, on the other hand, would be native iOS and Android apps.

I’m looking for a way to prepare the server in such a way, that it can be used by all the kinds of clients I mentioned (if possible). I considered WCF, ServiceStack and ASP.NET Web API. Even though I know little about these technologies, they seem to serve client requests only, and there is no permanent connection (right?). So I started wondering how to keep clients up-to-date as far as user statuses are concerned (the clients will show user statuses: online, offline etc.) IMO polling the server is not a good solution.

**I will be grateful for your suggestions on:**

1. what technology to use for the server so it is easy to communicate
   with from different platforms,
2. the best/easiest and efficient solution for notifying clients about changes (which
   may occur very often in this case).

Comment: 1. ServiceStack has c# client code for Android and iOS, i think, it can be build using Xamarin (but, i'm not 100%-sure). You can consider using xmpp protocol implementation. Xmpp is a chat protocol. Here you can find components for c#, Java, ObjectiveC (iOS) http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Comment: 2. xmpp has notification extension. http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html.

Comment: I think I was too general writing that it is going to by a chat system. Chat is only one of its basic features. I just wanted to point out this way that I want the server be able to send any kind of notifications to connected clients at any time.

Comment: If it comes to Xamarin, I came across it during my research I had done before writing this post. But I'm quite hesitant... I think I prefer writing native apps.

Comment: One of the possible methods: You can open TCP connection from client to server for notifications. When server need to send notification, it just write it to open client connection. Pros: no NAT problem, no need to establish connection for notification from server. Cons: draining server resources - connections must be always open.

Comment: What do you think about WebSocket? http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps

Comment: I think, it's not necessary. As I undertand, you have full-control over Windows server - so you can open standard TCP connections. And you creating native mobile apps (so it's easy to open connection on client-side). Websocket is good, when you need to open connections from Javascript or etc. Or when you can't open socket connections on server-side.